# attempting to load .csv file into several different arrays but python gives me an 'out of memory' error

Tags: python, out-of-memory, jython

I am attempting to read a .csv file into 7 different arrays.

The first array is for the names of the columns and takes the first 6 values of the csv file as the column names are at the begging.

After those 6 names have been recorded in the array it the (should) transition to reading the rows of the csv files and storing the values of each column in the own array IE the column called names has it's own array and so on for the next 5.

When i attempt to run this code it gives me a 'out of memory' error. Now the .csv file is very small (1kb) and a such it should definitely not be giving me this error (running 16GB of 2333mhz RAM)

**Code:**

```
 for line in data:
i = 0
counter = 0
# Split the line into its six values
seven = line.split(",")
# And append them (converted if necessary) to their arrays
while i < 6:
      array1.append(seven[counter])
      i + 1
      counter + 1
counter = 0
i = 0
while i < 60:

      array2.append(seven[counter])
      i + 1
      array3.append(float(seven[counter]))
      i + 1
      array4.append(float(seven[counter]))
      i + 1
      array5.append(float(seven[counter]))
      i + 1
      array6.append(float(seven[counter]))
      i + 1
      array7.append(float(seven[counter]))
      i + 1
      counter + 1
# And close the file
data.close
```

The error occurs on the line

```
array1.append(seven[counter])
```

the error is as follows given by my IDE

> "The error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError has occured"

Comment: Disregarding all the ways in which this is terrible code, your problem is that you're not updating the value of `i` so there's an infinite loop. You need to do `i += 1`. Better approach: Use the `csv` module.

Comment: Thankyou thats really helpful and yeah sorry about the 'terrible code' I'm just self teaching for something fun to do in my spare time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a handy [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) module that makes all of this easier for you. I'd suggest using the `DictReader` class, it automatically figures out the field names from the first row and then returns dictionaries. Don't create seven separate lists, that's just asking for trouble.

```
import csv
data = []
with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

# Accessing the 'name' field from row 32:
print data[32]['name']
```

Using the `with` statement saves you from having to call `.close()` manually.

You can make this even more concise with a call to the `list` constructor:

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I'm just self teaching in my spare time for something fun to do. Didn't even realize there was a csv module, will be using that from now on haha. :)

Comment: @samz1112 No worries, we all start somewhere! Python tries to come "batteries included" -- there's usually going to be a library to help you with all sorts of basic (and advanced!) stuff.

Comment: The code can be even a little simpler by replacing the `for` loop by `data = list(reader)`.  Or even `data = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))` so the `with` body becomes a one-liner.

Comment: @BlackJack Yep, that's usually how I would do it but I figured clarity beats conciseness for an absolute beginner. Still, good idea to edit in the short version.

Comment: Hm, that's not a list comprehension but a simple function call.